# Suzuki Swift engine squeal

Tags: automatic-transmission

I have a 2006 Suzuki Swift 1.5 auto. with the following problem:-

I've had a "squeal" from what I believe is the engine belts for 6 months now. Last January the belts were replaced by my garage but that and a further subsequent attempt to tighten has not solved the problem. 
The "squeal" occurs  when I first start the engine (usually in the morning) but not when it is idling only when I put it into drive and lasts for about a minute.
Any ideas?

Comment: Same here. For me, it goes away faster when I excessively switch through gears up and down in this phase.